# Why private static field is null?

Tags: c#, static

I have fields:

```
private static string ConnCms = ConnectionStrings.ConnCms;
private static string ConnSite = ConnectionStrings.ConnSite;
```

Why is it that when I call `SetTargetDB()`, the `ConnCms` and  `ConnSite` is `null`?
I also tried to put in `ConnCms` a string like "blabla" and the value still is `null`.

```
private void SetTargetDB(TargetDB value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case TargetDB.MainDB:
            connectionString = ConnectionStrings.isCms? ConnCms : ConnCms2 ;
            break;
        case TargetDB.UsersMaariv:
            connectionString = ConnUser;
            break;
        case TargetDB.JpostUsers:
            connectionString = ConnUser;
            break;
    }
}
```

This may be is important data to help you help me:
I have a only private instances of this class (singleton class)

private static NewDBAccess instance = new NewDBAccess(XXX);

Comment: What is the code in `ConnectionStrings.ConnCms`? It must be that this code is returning `null`

Comment: `ConnectionStrings.ConnCms` most probably returns null at the time when the `static string ConnCms` is initialized. Most probably this value is set later.

Comment: Are the `ConnectionStrings` present in the config file of the executing application or stored somewhere else ie another library? They must be present in the assembly that calls this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that static members declaration/instantiation, constructors always work out before anything else. So unless ConnectionStrings.ConnCms and ConnectionStrings.ConnSite are static properties and they were already instantiated it's very logical that they are not loaded at the time. Thats why you got  `null` values.

You can split it into two parts. In first part declare your static members. And later in your code assign values to them.

```
private static string ConnSite;
private static string ConnCms;

private void SetTargetDB(TargetDB value)
{
    ConnCms = ConnectionStrings.ConnCms;
    ConnSite = = ConnectionStrings.ConnSite;
    switch (value)
    {
        case TargetDB.MainDB:
            connectionString = ConnectionStrings.isCms? ConnCms : ConnCms2 ;
            break;
        case TargetDB.UsersMaariv:
            connectionString = ConnUser;
            break;
        case TargetDB.JpostUsers:
            connectionString = ConnUser;
            break;
    }
}
```

But your question provides too little information to figure out what's happening and why. Add some additional info...

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionStrings.ConnCms` most probably returns null at the time when the `static string ConnCms` is initialized. Most probably this value is set later.

Comment: While technically correct, this doesn't really help OP as it doesn't solve the issue. I'd leave it at a comment requesting clarification.

Comment: Usually, when someone understands the problem, he can easily solve it (or not that easily, but independently) .

Comment: Yeah but the purpose of SO is to solve the problem in your answer, not stating the obvious. Debugging hints go in comments, solutions go in answers. If OP doesn't want to cooperate to clarify the problem, don't answer.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger this can lead to ignoring smth like 90% of all questions on SO. Some people even don't know the basics.

Comment: I don't agree. 1) If it would be obvious for the OP, he wouldn't ask. 2) You cannot do the coding for other people on SO. You can only help with very specific problems. I considered the area where the ConnectionStrings are initialized, and how and from where, as outside of the question. The overall design and coding and debugging is still done by the people who ask questions. We cannot do everything for them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ConnectionStrings` is  a `struct` or `class`, you would need to place it in the block of code which is called absolutely first (after everything else that is required for the basic infrastructure).  For instance, typically in Visual Studio, there will be a Class Method with a Doc Comment above it that says something like

```
namespace YourAppNS {

    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        // Constructor for MainWindow Class
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            /** This is where you want to place any initializers
                to the variables (e.g. ConnectionStrings) in order
                to have them be non-null when called.  Again, depending
                on your implementation, you may need ConnectionStrings
                object to be either public, protected internal, or 
                global. Again, other than mentioning this is a singleton
                class...are all of the methods contained inside also? */
        }
    }
 }
```

C# differs greatly in some respects from my programming language of choice - C and C++ - one of those differences is the lack of being able to define constant #define preprocessor macros or *truly constant, immutable & static objects* initialized at the inception of the application.  While it can be done (somewhat) through some fairly complex and troublesome hacks...the best thing to do is find the area where your code will first start execution. Then call the methods which need to be initialized so that they contain valid data.

Also, make sure you have the proper access specifiers (e.g. public, protected internal, etc.) on the ConnectionStrings object.  If it is a struct, depending on the particulars of the code, you might have to make sure each item inside the structure is *also* classified public.  Or define it with a { get; set; } vs. a simple static declaration.

I hope this helps somewhat, I was going to make this a comment to your message, but it is similar to problems I've had when learning c#.  If you could provide a little more detail on the object types, how you're calling them, etc. maybe we could help more!

Good luck.